# dbms_audit_mgmt.clean_audit_trail not purging

Tags: plsql, audit

my current database version is 11.2.0.3.0. I'm trying to purge my audit trail with a procedure. In my procedure I got this part of code:

```
SYS.dbms_audit_mgmt.clean_audit_trail(
audit_trail_type        =>  SYS.dbms_audit_mgmt.audit_trail_aud_std,
use_last_arch_timestamp => TRUE
);
```

I'm not running the procedure under SYS so there is SYS.dbms...in the code.
Everything is working without errors. But audit trail from sys.aud$ table is not purged!

Any ideas, why it's not working?

I read that: Bug 9164488 - DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.CLEAN_AUDIT_TRAIL does not delete sys.aud$ and sys.fga_log$ tables ID 9164488.8+ was fixed in 11.2.0.2 version, so this should not be the case.

Also setting last archive timestamp is working fine!

```
SYS.dbms_audit_mgmt.set_last_archive_timestamp(
 audit_trail_type  => SYS.dbms_audit_mgmt.audit_trail_aud_std,
 last_archive_time => to_timestamp(SYSDATE - pocet_dnu),
 rac_instance_number  => null
);
```

Thanks

Honza

Comment: unfortunately I have to do this using dbms_audit_mgmt package, otherwise I would delete it manually.